# Python ping by reading txt file contain list of IP address and string or name next to it

Tags: python, ping, txt

I'm testing running simple script to ping few servers by calling a text file iplist.txt. The script working if txt file only contain IP address. Now I'm adding hostname next to the IP address in the iplist.txt and ping failed.

```
Original only IP address in iplist.txt
192.168.1.1 
192.168.1.2 

Updated with name string in iplist.txt
192.168.1.1 server1
192.168.1.2 server2
```

I think the issue is the strip part,

```
def iplist() :
    # Grab list of IP from the file
    pingList = open("iplist.txt", "r")
    for i in pingList:
       ip = i[-15:]
       ip = ip.strip(' ')
       ip = ip.strip('\n')
       with open(os.devnull, 'w') as DEVNULL:
            try:
                subprocess.check_call(
                   ['ping', '-w', '1', ip],
                   stdout = DEVNULL, 
                   stderr = DEVNULL
                )
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: `ip = i[-15:]` returns the last 15 characters of the line.  That makes no sense for reading the `ip`.  Use `ip = i.split()[0]` to split on whitespace and return the first thing in the line.

Comment: ‘print(ip)‘ before issuing ping at take a look at printout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're getting your IP addresses from the file makes no sense. All you need to do is split each line by spaces and then get the first token (with `ip = i.split(' ')[0]`). Like this:

```
def iplist() :
    # Grab list of IP from the file
    pingList = open("iplist.txt", "r")
    for i in pingList:
       ip = i.split(' ')[0]
       with open(os.devnull, 'w') as DEVNULL:
            try:
                subprocess.check_call(
                   ['ping', '-w', '1', ip],
                   stdout = DEVNULL, 
                   stderr = DEVNULL
                )
```